# Add/Remove classes not working for some reason

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var vaStyle = $("nav.global_nav, .rsGCaption .intro-caption");
var vid_detach = $("div.rsCloseVideoBtn");
var vid_launch = $("h1#vidLaunch");

vid_launch.click(function () {
    vaStyle.addClass("hprs-video-active");
}); 
vid_detach.click(function(){
    vaStyle.removeClass("hprs-video-active");
});
```

Why isn't my removeClass working? Is there a better method?
Also, when you declare a var does it work document-wide?

Comment: Are you sure that your `click` event is firing? Have you tried to place a breakpoint there?

Comment: Are the `vaStyle` elements getting dynamically added?

Comment: its not — the class isn't being removed... no breakpoints. thanks.

Comment: What about the second question: read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript and http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: Place the breakpoint and check if this function is being called. If it isn't then the problem is not in `addClass` \ `removeClass`, but in your click handler.

Comment: When do you run this snippet? for debug purposes try add `console.log(vaStyle.size());` in order to check if the element is correctly selected.

Comment: Please, reproduce this problem at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: missed the closing colon on the second var call (smacks head)... thanks guys.

Comment: wait. thats not the problem... the rsCloseVideoBtn button is generated _after_ the vid_launch. In other words, clicking the vid_launch activates the button, it is not present at DOM ready. is there a way to bind the function to the button, before it is in the DOM? Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your elements are getting added dynamically. Use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** for solving this. I made changes to the event binding.

```
var vaStyle = $("nav.global_nav, .rsGCaption .intro-caption");
var vid_detach = "div.rsCloseVideoBtn";
var vid_launch = "h1#vidLaunch";

$(document).on('click', vid_launch, function () {
    vaStyle.addClass("hprs-video-active");
}); 
$(document).on('click', vid_detach, function () {
    vaStyle.removeClass("hprs-video-active");
});
```

Comment: thanks. was looking at on function just now. will try.

Comment: You aren't delegating event here, `selector` parameter has to be a string selector, here you are passing `vid_launch` & `vid_detach` as event data

Comment: only the vid_detach is being added dynamically so the script above isn't working... but thanks.